# Using same javascript function multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I got an javascript onclick function that (should) listen to a specific a tag based on the current score. It´s for a quiz. The onlick function listens for the click on the right answer (has class right). In the beginnig the right answer that the function should listen to is the first a tag with the class right. After this answer has been clicked the function should get executed and the question changes and the score is raised by one. Now the function should listen to the second a tag with the right class. I got a variable `score2` that always is the value needed to select the right a tag but it ins´t working. 
The Code:

```
var score = 0
var score2 = 0
    document.getElementById("go").onclick = function() {
    score++;
    console.log(score);
    console.log(score2);
    document.getElementById("head").style.display="inline";
    document.getElementById("question0").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("question1").style.display="block";
};

document.getElementsByClassName("right")[score].onclick = function(){
score++;
score2++;
//console.log(score);
console.log(score2);
document.getElementById("question"+score2).style.display="none";
document.getElementById("question"+score).style.display="inline";
};
```

and the html (the quiz is in german)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body">
    <div id="inbody">
    <div id="question0">
        <h1>
            WELCOME TO THE 100 QUESTION GAME!
        </h1>

        <h2 id="go" style="color:pink">
        Lets GO!
    </h2>
    <p>
        by strawberry studios
    </p>

</div>

<div id="head" style="display:none;">
    <h1>THE 100 QUESTION GAME</h1>
</div>


<div id="question1" style="display:none;">
    <h3>
        Von wo aus kann man nur nach S&uuml;den gehen?
    </h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id="questionOneAnswerOne" class="right">Nordpol</a> <br> <!--Richtig-->
    <a id="questionOneAnswerTwo" class="wrong" href="http://100questiongame.tk/index.html">S&uuml;dpol</a> <br>
    <a id="questionOneAnswerThree" href="http://100questiongame.tk/index.html" class="wrong">&Auml;quator</a> <br>
    <a id="questionOneAnswerFour" class="wrong" href="http://100questiongame.tk/index.html">Bayern</a> <br>
</div>

<div id="question2" style="display:none;">
    <h3>
        Was ist am teuersten?
    </h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id="questionTwoAnswerOne" href="http://100questiongame.tk/index.html" class="wrong">Diamant</a> <br>
    <a id="quoestionTwonswerTwo" href="http://100questiongame.tk/index.html" class="wrong">Platin</a> <br>
    <a id="questionTwoAnswerThree" href="http://100questiongame.tk/index.html" class="wrong">Gold</a> <br>
    <a id="questionTwoAnswerFour" class="right">Osmium</a> <br> <!--Richtig-->
</div>

<div id="question3" style="display:none;">
    <h3>
        Wof&uuml;r steht HTML?
    </h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id="questionThreeAnswerOne" href="http://100questiongame.tk/index.html" class="wrong">Hyper Text Multiple Language</a> <br>
    <a id="questionThreeAnswerTwo" href="http://100questiongame.tk/index.html" class="wrong">Hyper Text Markup Language</a> <br> <!--Richtig-->
    <a id="questionThreeAnswerThree" class="right">Hydrotecinmultiliquid</a> <br>
    <a id="questionThreeAnswerFour" href="http://100questiongame.tk/index.html" class="wrong">Hype The Mother (a)lLong<a/> <br>
</div>

<div id="question4" style="display:none;">
    <h3>
        Welche Farbe h&auml;tte Cola ohne Farbstoffe?
    </h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id="questionFourAnswerOne" href="http://100questiongame.tk/index.html" class="wrong">Gelb</a> <br>
    <a id="questionFouranswerTwo" href="http://100questiongame.tk/index.html" class="wrong">Erdbraun</a> <br>
    <a id="questionFourAnswerThree" class="right">Grün</a> <br> <!--Richtig-->
    <a id="questionFourAnswerFour" href="http://100questiongame.tk/index.html" class="wrong">Türkis<a/> <br>
</div>

<div id="question5 "tyle="display:none;">

</div>

<div id="question6" style="display:none;">

</div>

<div id="question7" style="display:none;">

</div>

<div id="question8" style="display:none;">

</div>

<div id="question9" style="display:none;">

</div>

<div id="question10" style="display:none;">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

got to http://100questiongame.tk to test the code and go to https://floobits.com/BenBals/quiz.sublime-project to see the code live as I editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to do it:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/97gCk/3/

```
<div id="question1" style="display:none">
    <h3>
        Von wo aus kann man nur nach S&uuml;den gehen?
    </h3>
    <br><br>
    <a id="question1_1" onclick="nextQuestion(this)" href="#">Nordpol</a><br>
    <a id="question1_2" class="wrong" href="..">S&uuml;dpol</a><br>
    <a id="question1_3" class="wrong" href="..">&Auml;quator</a><br>
    <a id="question1_4" class="wrong" href="..">Bayern</a><br>
</div>
```

JS

```
var score = 1;

document.getElementById("go").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("go").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("question"+score).style.display="block";
};

function nextQuestion (el){
    el.style.color="green";
    document.getElementById("question"+score).style.display="none";
    score++;
    document.getElementById("question"+score).style.display="inline";    
};
```

Comment: since I new here is there any like thank you function.

Comment: No there isn't, just write a comment with your message to the comment poster or answer poster.